# iOS 5 Twitter Integration, Parsing current URL

Tags: iphone, xcode, parsing, twitter, integration

Ok so I am trying to integrate twitter into my iPhone app.  I have a UIWebView, and when the user presses the tweet button, I would like the current url to be prefilled into a tweet using the twitter addURL method.  The problem is that the current url is formatted for mobile devices, and I would like tweets to show the full version of the website.  All of the tweets would link to the same domain, so here are the link formats that I am dealing with.

Mobile URL:  http://www.website.com/mobile/news/**123456**

Fullsite URL: http://www.website.com/podium/default.aspx?t=204&nid=**123456**

What I have done so far (just showing part of the twitter integration code):

```
  [twitter addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.website.com/podium/default.aspx?t=204&nid="]]];
```

So my question is, is there a way to take the identifying numbers from the mobile site and append them onto the fullsite that will be included in the tweet?  I just don't know much about parsing url's (if that is what needs to be done in this situation) so any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Because you are using stringWithFormat you just need to add a format string to your argument. Let's say that you have the id as an int variable called theID:

int myID = 123456;
[twitter addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.website.com/podium/default.aspx?t=204&nid=%i", myID]]];

I suggest taking a look at the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-CJBEAEHH) for clarification.

Comment: Ok so the problem is that the myID is not constant, it depends on whatever the id of in the mobile website.  How can I take the last 6 digits from the mobile website and make it a variable?  I'll take a look at the guide, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I do not know if you have the url variable as an NSURL or an NSString, but both of them have a method called lastPathComponent that will get the id that you need. It does just what it says, looks at the path you provide and gives you the last component.